# Запятая на стыке союзов (при союзе "а")

Tags: союзы

Почему Розенталь пишет, что при союзе "а" изъятие или перестановка придаточной части невозможны. Следовательно, на стыке союза "а" с каким-либо другим союзом запятая не ставится.
Возьмем пример:

> Книжка пошла по рядам, и каждый ее рассматривал, а когда она дошла до
> меня, я открыл ее и прочел...

Перестроить же можно, причем смысл сохранится:

> Каждый ее рассматривал, а я открыл ее и прочел, когда она дошла до
> меня

Comment: *Ajgy*, добрый день! Советую внести исправления: при союзе «а» (в шапке); поставить точку или многоточие после слов "до меня"; использовать метки "запятая" и "союзы".

Comment: Речь именно о стыке союзов и о самом правиле. Вопрос не о запятой.

Comment: Нельзя для каждого вопроса придумывать новые метки — мы в них зароемся. Необходимо использовать уже имеющиеся. Не нравится "запятая" (а она у Вас, кстати, есть в заголовке), поставьте "пунктуация". Например, метка "запятая-на-стыке-союзов" является синонимом, и вопросы объединяются.

Comment: Я думаю, в первоначальной фразе не хватает того, что "я прочел". Например, "я ее открыл и прочел: "на помощь". Тогда перестановка будет звучать криво, как излишнее дополнение: Каждый ее рассматривал, а я открыл ее и прочел: "на помощь", - когда она дошла до меня. Не понятно про что фраза, то ли про прочитанное, то ли про то что она дошла до меня.

Comment: Цитата или ссылка на Розенталя есть? У него несколько справочников.

Comment: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=140

Comment: Заголовок лишь отсылает к правилу, которое меня интересует, а правило так и называется: "Запятая на стыке двух союзов".  Тут нет никакого противоречия.

Comment: В исходном варианте нет противопоставления: *Каждый рассматривал, а я открыл.* И ещё: "прочёл книжку" означает, что полностью прочитал (что нелогично), лучше: *почитал*.

Comment: Ajgy, мне почему-то сразу не приходит уведомление. Сейчас гляну.

Comment: Это пример из НКРЯ. А почему нет? Ведь и в исходном примере есть противопоставление! Или вы о том, что противопоставляются другие элементы друг другу?

Comment: Его нет в исходном. Сложно объяснить. Пока не знаю как. "А" относится к придаточному, поэтому и запятую не ставим. Чтобы было противопоставление, надо отнести "а" к главному и после него сделать паузу (что вообще не получается).

Comment: Что этим хотел сказать: что предложение меняется, после перестановки не то же самое. Ещё придаточное становится присоединительным.

Comment: @Ajgy Лингвисты с этим принципом запутались. В справочнике на Грамоте был такой пример: *Вот видишь ли, – говорю, – сестрица: ты тогда на меня сердилась, а, значит, я говорил правду.* Мол, раз "значит" можно изъять... Но запятой не должно быть, потому что оно расшифровывается как: *ты тогда на меня сердилась, а это значит, что я говорил правду*. Теперь там нет этого примера.